# cypress rightclick an element while still in focus

Tags: cypress, contextmenu, highlight

I'm new to Cypress.
Is it possible to show a context menu and select a menu while the another element is still in focus?

```
cy.get('#id1').rightclick({force:true}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/rightclick)

> `.rightclick()` will not open context menus native to the browser.
> `.rightclick()` should be used to test your app's handling of right click related events such as `contextmenu`.

But without some way to know you have "native" contextmenu, it only tells you that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Since you tried it and are asking the question, it looks like you have "native" contextmenu.

**Note** - focus does not seem to apply to `.rightclick()` as it does to `.click()`, since there is an example `cy.focused().rightclick()` - this implies that the action does not give focus or take it away from another element.

Instead, I would try [cypress-real-events - realclick](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealclick) (only works on chromium browsers).

**Installation**

```js
npm install cypress-real-events
// or
yarn add cypress-real-events
```

**Test**

```js
import "cypress-real-events";
...
cy.get('#id1').realClick({button: 'right'})
```